# How could I display the source file.php in HTML?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have the following PHP script (file.php) which shows the current time and displays the user's input:

```
Current time:

<?php

$time=time();
$actual_time=date('H:i:s',$time);
echo $actual_time;

//show user input
$enter=@$_POST['enter'];
echo '<br>Input: '.$enter;

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="enter">
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

By default the page shows this:
[image: default]

If I enter e.g. `<strong>test</strong>`, I see this:
[image: enter_htmlcode1]

And if I enter `<iframe src="file.php"></iframe>`, I can reload the page in a smaller window:
[image: enter_htmlcode2]

So, now, how could I display the raw PHP script (file.php) by submitting some certain HTML code in the INPUT text field?

Comment: [highlight_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php)

Comment: iframe is not your answer.

Comment: @MarkBaker If I enter something like `<?php highlight_file(file.php) ?>`, I don't see anything.

Comment: You won't see anything...... unless you bother to echo it, and recognise that `file.php` should be a string containing the file name: `<?php echo highlight_file('file.php'); ?>`.... this is where actually reading the documentation helps you

Comment: @MarkBaker well, there is still nothing shown? Somehow, `echo` is not processed at all.

Comment: Any errors of any kind? (e.g. in log files?)? Something like this doesn't simply "not work".... but I can't debug it for you

Comment: @MarkBaker I need to look up how to create log files, but here, indeed, I don't get any errors at all, even if I remove the `@` in `$enter=@$_POST['enter'];`

Comment: @Andy So let me get your problem straight, you want to give a filename(say `file.php`) as input and when you hit enter, it should display the contents of the file, right?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? If you want to attack the site - no you can not achieve this (with this sources) - at most it will be `XSS`. If you try to show sources for a legimate reason - you have to change a code and use for example `<?php echo highlight_file('file.php'); ?>`

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk I don't want to attack any site except of mine, I want to test it against such attacks... if `iframe` is the only thing that a user could mess around, then I can say that my site is secure?

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk I call a site insecure, if it is possible to get the source code of it

Comment: @Andy It is a very simple difinition of insecurity. Some sites have public source code - and are secure. Many sites use Open Source software - for example - Wordpress, Wikipedia, or Stackoverflow and are nevertheless secure. Your source code has XSS - one of Top 10 vulnerabilities on the web. It does not allow to reveal your source code, but some other stuff. More information at [OWASP Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php

// Disable a WebKit security feature
// which would prevent from showing the source code.
header('X-XSS-Protection: 0');

if (isset($_GET['source']) || isset($_POST['source'])) {
        $source = file_get_contents(__FILE__);

        // To prevent this control from showing up
        // in the output source code
        // enable the code below.
        /*
        $lines_to_remove = 26;
        $source = explode("\n", $source, $lines_to_remove);
        $source = $source[$lines_to_remove - 1];
        */

        $source = highlight_string($source, true);
        echo $source;

        return;
}

?>
Current time:

<?php


$time=time();
$actual_time=date('H:i:s',$time);
echo $actual_time;

//show user input
$enter=@$_POST['enter'];
echo '<br>Input: '.$enter;

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="enter">
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: thx! for completeness: the input has to be `<iframe src="file.php?source"></iframe>`

Answer (score 3):

## First

```
htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities

$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new;

//This would be the output
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;

//browser will display
<a href='test'>Test</a>
```

## Second

```
htmlentities -Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;

echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;

In browser it woulbe displayed:

A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the input as plain text should display the file:

```
<?php

$time=time();
$actual_time=date('H:i:s',$time);
echo $actual_time;

//show user input
$enter=@$_POST['enter'];

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

echo '<br>Input: '.$enter;

?>
```

Of course you would then have to customize your script to detect when the user wants to display the file, and only then change the content type (or else the other html inputs will not work).

Comment: Well, it works.. but I was actually hoping to display the file without modifying it.

Comment: Modifying which file? You are talking about `file.php`? Because unless the script *is* `file.php`, you will not be modifying it.

Comment: yes, I mean the file `file.php`. What I am intending to do, is to give an input and then return the file on the screen.

Comment: @Andy wants to use an exploit to see the file, I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

Submitting html or php code to then display:

```
<?php

$time=time();
$actual_time=date('H:i:s',$time);
echo $actual_time;

//show user input
$enter=@$_POST['enter'];
echo '<br>Input: <pre>'.htmlspecialchars($enter).'</pre>';

?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="enter">
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

Opening a file and then display:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("test.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(fread($myfile,filesize("test.php"))).'</pre>';
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

File name : test1.php

Write below code in this file :

```
<?php
$time=time();
$actual_time=date('H:i:s',$time): ;
echo $actual_time;

$enter=@$_POST['enter'];
if (isset($enter)) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($enter);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
           $file_name = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
    if(isset($file_name)){
        $result ='<iframe src='.$file_name.'></iframe>';        
    }else{
        $result = $enter;   
    }
}
echo '<br>Input: '.$result;
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="enter">
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

Create a new file : test6.php

Write code below in this file :

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("test1.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(fread($myfile,filesize("test1.php"))).'</pre>';
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Hit file : test1.php

write in input tag : `<iframe src="test6.php"></iframe>`

It will work !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve, however, I assume the `highlight_file()` function should help.

```
echo highlight_file('file.php',true);
```